# Adjusting Regex to remove trailing decimal point + zeroes if there is no fraction

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to learn Regex.

Currently I'm trying to write a function that parses a float and sets a "maximum" number of decimal places (basically only allows two decimal points, but doesn't add them if there is no content - i.e. gets rid of the 0's in X.00 to return X.).  Here's the code:

```
price_var.toFixed(2).replace(/0{0,2}$/, "");
```

It works well removing the zeros, but doesn't remove the decimal place.  Is there a way to also get rid of the decimal place if there is no fraction?

Comment: Include the period character in the pattern to match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
price_var.toFixed(2).replace(/\.0{0,2}$/, "");
```

since it is a fixed decimal points, try

```
price_var.toFixed(2).replace(/\.0{2}$/, "");
```

or

```
price_var.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00$/, "");
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly.  Now to figure out the structure.